# Cannot get into wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I logged into the WordPress dashboard, which prompted me to update, so I did and then waited 10 minutes and when I tried to log back in it gave me a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   wp_get_active_and_valid_themes()

Please help me fix this.

Comment: may be it's still updating

Comment: i will continue to check

Comment: The update process generally takes a few seconds, few minutes tops. It sounds like the update was stopped mid-process or otherwise failed. If the front end and back end of the site are not working still, you'll likely need to manually update WordPress - upload a clean install to the server with FTP, overriding all of WordPress except the wp-config.php & wp-content folders.

Comment: Oh boy, why can't wordpress just work, I started using wordpress so I wouldn't have to worry about things like this.